# Teechart: how remove values from legend?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm trying to customize Teechart Pie. Now it looks this:
[image: pie chart]

As you can see, there are values and names in the legend. How can I remove values and leave only names in the legend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to force the legend to only show the labels:

```
tChart1.getLegend().setTextStyle(LegendTextStyle.PLAIN);
```

Comment: Also can you please say how to increase pie height? I didn't find any simple way to do this. Thank you.